# Polymer 1.0 in Ember-cli, wrong appearance

Tags: javascript, ember.js, polymer, frontend, ember-cli

I have managed to integrate Polymer 1.0 to my Ember-cli project.
This my Brocfile

```
var vulcanize = require('broccoli-vulcanize');
var pickFiles = require('broccoli-static-compiler');
var mergeTrees = require('broccoli-merge-trees');
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');


var app = new EmberApp({
  compassOptions: {
    sassDir: "app/styles/main",
    outputStyle: 'expanded'
  }
});

//app.import("./bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js");

var polymerVulcanize = vulcanize('app', {
    input: 'elements.html',
    output: 'assets/vulcanized.html',
/*    inline: true,
    strip: false,*/
    excludes: [/*/^data:/, /^http[s]?:/, /^\//*/],
   /* stripExcludes: false,
    stripComments: false,
    inlineScripts: false,*/
    inlineCss: true
  })
  ;
var polymer = pickFiles('bower_components/', {
  srcDir: '',
  files: [
    'webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js',
    'polymer/polymer.html'
//  'polymer/polymer.js'
  ],
  destDir: '/assets'
});

//Bootstrap

app.import('./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js');
app.import('./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```

This how I include everything:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Front</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="assets/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  {{content-for 'head'}}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/front.css">
  <script src="assets/vendor.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/front.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="assets/vulcanized.html">
  {{content-for 'head-footer'}}
</head>
<body>
{{content-for 'body'}}
{{content-for 'body-footer'}}
</body>
</html>
```

And this my buttons in index.hbs

```
<paper-spinner active></paper-spinner>
<paper-button>flat button</paper-button>
<paper-button raised>raised button</paper-button>
```

What I have in result is wrong rendered buttons 1 of 4/5 times.

This how it looks:
[image]

And normal:
[image]

If Im right the problem in paper-material, but I have no idea what to do.
[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have been trying to use polymer 1.0 with ember for the last month, turns out some polymer elements that use  as insertion points will not work with ember.

I have spoken with a polymer core member and he said they are curerntly working in some interop to get things working but it should take some time.

I have opened an issue on emberjs repo(https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11361), you can follow there as well.

Try to move your code from `index.hbs` in `index.html` instead, this will solve the problem but these elements will not work under any route.

Comment: Fwiw, when all browsers implement the Shadow DOM standard, this problem will go away completely. It's only a problem today because of the need to shim Shadow DOM. Support Shadow DOM!